# HTTPS connection stops working after a few minutes

Tags: ssl, https, azure-service-fabric, traefik

I have the following setup:

- Service Fabric cluster running 5 machines, with several services running in Docker containers
- A public IP which has port 443 open, forwarding to the service running Traefik
- Traefik terminates the SSL, and proxies the request over to the service being requested over HTTP

Here's the behavior I get:

- The first request to https:// is very, very slow.  Chrome will usually eventually load it after a time timeouts or "no content" errors.  Invoke-WebRequest in Powershell usually just times out with an "The underlying connection was closed" message.
- However, once it loads, I can refresh things or run the command again and it responds very, very quickly.  It'll work as long as there's regular traffic to the URL.
- If I leave for a bit (not sure on the time, definitely a few minutes) it dies and goes back to the beginning.

My Question:

What would cause SSL handshakes to just break or take forever?  What component in this stack is to blame?  Is something in Service Fabric timing out?  Is it a Traefik thing?  I could switch over to Nginx if it's more stable.  We use these same certs on IIS, and we don't have this problem.

I could use something like New Relic to constantly send a ping every minute to keep things alive, but I'd rather figure out why the connection is dying after a few minutes.

What are the best ways to go about debugging this?  I don't see anything in the Traefik log files (In DEBUG mode), in fact when it doesn't connect, there's no record of the request in the access logs at all.  Any tools that could help debug this?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using local cluster for your tests?

Comment: This is on Azure..

Answer (score 1):

Is the Traefik service healthy on **all** 5 nodes, can you inspect the logs of all 5 instances? If not this might cause the Azure Load Balancer to load balance across nodes where Traefik is not listening which would cause intermittent and slow responses. Once a healthy Traefik responds, you'll get a sticky session cookie which will then make subsequent responses faster. You can enable ApplicationInsights monitoring for Traefik logs to save you crawling across all the machines: https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric#debugging. I'd also recommend testing this without SSL to ensure Traefik can route correctly over HTTP first and then add HTTPS. That way you'll know it's something to do with the SSL configuration (i.e. mounted the certificates correctly, Traefik toml config, trusted certificates, etc.)